# Pylint: Relative import should be

Tags: python, pylint

I'm checking a module with Pylint. The project has this structure:

```
/builder
    __init__.py
    entity.py
    product.py
```

Within product I import entity like this:

```
from entity import Entity
```

but Pylint laments that:

```
************* Module builder.product
W:  5,0: Relative import 'entity', should be 'builder.entity'
```

However `from builder.entity import Entity` doesn't recognize the package, and `from ..builder.entity import Entity` doesn't work either. What is Pylint complaining about? Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python 2.5 introduces relative imports. They allow you to do

```
from .entity import Entity
```

Answer (score 10):

The __init__.py file makes pylint think your code is a package (namely "builder").

Hence when pylint see "from entity import Entity", it detects it properly as an implicit
relative import (you can do explicit relative import using '.' since python 2.6, as other posters have advertised) and reports it.

Then, if "from builder.entity import Entity" doesn't work, it's a PYTHONPATH pb : ensure the directory containing the "builder" directory is in your PYTHONPATH (an alternative pb being proposed by gurney alex). Unless you didn't intended to write a package, then removing the __init__.py is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What do you get if you include the following lines at the top of product.py:

```
import builder
print builder
```

My guess is that you are importing a different module / package `builder` from some place in your PYTHONPATH which is before what you're using.

Answer (score -1):

glglgl's answer is correct if you have a newer Python version.

However if you don't you must just make sure that the package you are validating is in your `PYTHONPATH`. See the examples below.

```
[sebastian ~/tmp/testpy]$ pylint -r n a.py 
************* Module a
C:  1: Missing docstring
F:  1: Unable to import 'testpy.b'
[sebastian ~/tmp/testpy]$ PYTHONPATH=".." pylint -r n a.py 
************* Module a
C:  1: Missing docstring
```

Comment: i do have __init__.py, thanks for pointing it out, i edited my question.